# GLSL - testing fragment world space coordinate intersection with geometry texture, and texture modification

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am exploring some GLSL and have something I want to try to implement.  Here is the situation:

I have a previously rendered texture which stores only world-space coordinates of fragments (rgb = xyz).  This texture is being passed to another render pass, is it possible take the world position texture and sample it to test the current fragments' world-space coordinate to see if they are a match?

An example could be 2 cameras, testing to see if any of the points in 3D space rendered to texture by camera A can also be seen by camera B.

Also, is it possible to have a texture that can be modified between several different shaders?  i.e. having a camera render a texture, then pass that texture to another shader and change it?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a previously rendered texture which stores only world-space coordinates of fragments (rgb = xyz). This texture is being passed to another render pass, is it possible take the world position texture and sample it to test the current fragments' world-space coordinate to see if they are a match?
>
> An example could be 2 cameras, testing to see if any of the points in 3D space rendered to texture by camera A can also be seen by camera B.

Yes, it is possible. This is essentially a shadow-map, but now you'll have to calculate the distances manually during the sampling. It's unclear why you insist on storing the world-space XYZ coordinates and what's the use-case of this. It should be much simpler and more efficient to store the depths in a depth texture and use the built-in depth-texture lookup.

> Also, is it possible to have a texture that can be modified between several different shaders? i.e. having a camera render a texture, then pass that texture to another shader and change it?

Yes. You can render a texture and then use `imageLoad` and `imageStore` (and related APIs) in another shader to modify it. You must be careful, however, with feedback loops. Because of the parallel nature of the GPUs, and their cache-incoherent architecture, it might be complicated and a detailed answer would depend on the exact thing you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! I am still wrapping my head around Shadow Mapping, so i will look deeper into that and see if I can tweak it to fit my needs, ah I was thinking of storing XYZ in a texture for a potential solution to the idea I am working on